# Understanding class as custom data types C#

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to understand how to use classes as custom data types. Hope to have a clarification of my understanding on it.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set }
}

public Employee Equipment { ... }
```

What is the use of the custom data type `Employee` on the property `Equipment`?

From my own reading, it means that `Equipment` can use the property `Id` in the `Employee` data type such that `Equipment.Id` is available to be used. Is my understanding correct?

I am very new to C# and have tried reading the C# documentation but still cannot fully understand this concept.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct but you need to create _an instance_ of the class in order to be able to use its members (properties, methods, etc.). To create a _new_ instance of the class, you can do something like `Equipment = new Employee();`. Then, you can get/set the values of its properties (e.g., `Equipment.Id = 5;`). For more information, you may read [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

Comment: @41686d6564 Thank you for your answer. I understand this now. :)

Comment: Think about a class as the definition of what you are calling a "custom data type". Once you have that definition you can create as many instances of that type as you want using `new`. Each of those instances (or objects) has the same properties and behavior (or methods), but each has a different identity and each can have different values for those properties. The class definition *encapsulates* bother the *shape* (/properties) and the *behavior* (/functionality) of the class. Most other *object oriented* languages implement the same basic concepts.